# Regex to match data between brackets and length of the string

Tags: regex

I'm using the following string:

```
02:05:31,624 TRACE [com.test.enterprise.process.module.AZZADM13] (default task-6) [2019-06-10][02:05:31][5330985][TESTSRV ][AZZADM13                 ][process - ENTER               ]
```

using regular expression I would like to match the TESTSRV.   To do so i need to match on a value that is in between 2 brackets, is a capital letter (A-Z) or a space and has a length of 10 (includes brackets) or length of 8 (does not include bracket).

Here is my starting expression:

```
\[([A-Z ]+)\]{10}
```

This matches the "in between brackets" but i can't seem to get the length to work.    Any advice appreciated.

In this example, i would expect to match on TESTSRV.

Comment: `\[([A-Z ]+)\]{10}` definitely won't work. It means you want one opening bracket, one or more chars of the form `[A-Z ]` then 10 closing brackets. I would go with `\[[A-Z ]{8}\]`. No point in trying to count the brackets since they're explicit.

Comment: This works as well...  I needed shift the location of the {10} to get it to match properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not sure what our other inputs would look like, my guess is that we might have optional spaces, and we can add those anywhere in our expression that is required:

```
\[[0-9]+\](\s+)?\[(\s+)?(.+?)(\s+)?\](\s+)?\[[A-Z0-9]
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/69errK/1/)

If optional spaces, `(\s+)?`, are unnecessary, we can simply remove any of `(\s+)?`.

Here, we have a left boundary:

```
\[[0-9]+\]
```

and a right boundary:

```
\[[A-Z0-9]
```

and our desired output is in this capturing group:

```
(.+?)
```

along with some optional spaces groups:

```
(\s+)?
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]